# http requests are being follow by non user requests with Dalvik user agent

Tags: android, http, dalvik

I have noticed in my logs that every time some of my logged users make a request a second "shadow" request follows. The second request has the same IP and target as the "normal" request but reduced headers. Every time, this opens a new session.

I have observed that this is common with tables.

Any ideas of what causes this?

Request header:

```
host=www.example.com
connection=keep-alive
accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=1
user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Lenovo YT3-X50F Build/LMY47V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.83 Safari/537.36
referer=https://www.example.com/auth/xyz
accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, sdch
accept-language=en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
cookie=JSESSIONID=XXXXX; _gat=1; _ga=GAXXXXXX
```

Shadow request header:

```
Headers=user-agent=Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; Lenovo YT3-X50F Build/LMY47V)
host=www.example.com
connection=Keep-Alive
accept-encoding=gzip
```